# Add custom HTML page when iis site is stopped

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I want to display an "under maintenance" html page when my site is stopped in iis automatically instead of manually adding the app_offline.htm everytime . Is it possible to route the url to the maintenance page automatically whenever the site is stopped? From what i understand when the site is stopped nothing is getting hit,So is there a way to reroute the path instead of keeping a proxy server? Right now i am getting a "**This site can’t be reached**. xx.x.x.x refused to connect."

Comment: If your words on "when my site is stopped" mean stopping the IIS site completely (so its site bindings are off), then IIS routes the requests to the catch-all site (usually the Default Web Site) on that machine, and you can set your maintenance notice page there.

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop a Web site, means the Web site no longer listens for requests on all of its bindings. This prevents any subsequent requests from being received by your applications in the Web site; new connections to your Web site will fail as if it didn't exist.

So first start your site and create a temporary page that is used to redirect all the pages.

Below is URL rewrite rule which redirects all the pages to the under-construction page:

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{URL}" pattern=".*" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="temp.html" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="temp.html" />
        </rule>
```

[image]